# Can't run Rails in Gem/Engine project without first installing the gem itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rails-engines

I just made a fresh checkout of my Rails Engine project, and when (after `bundle install`) I invoke `rails -v` in its root directory, I'm getting a `LoadError` in which Rails appears to be looking for the very gem/engine I'm trying to build:

```
my-engine dmoles$ rails -v
/Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'my-engine' (>= 0) among 117 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1:/Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

Running `gem env` as suggested provides no more enlightenment:

```
my-engine dmoles$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.1 (2015-02-26 patchlevel 85) [x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/dmoles/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1
     - /Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /Users/dmoles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin
     - /Users/dmoles/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin
     - /Users/dmoles/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/dmoles/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
```

I can build/install the gem fine with

```
gem build my-engine.gemspec
gem install my-engine-0.0.1.gem
```

after which `rails -v` starts working.* It doesn't seem like this should be necessary, though, and it makes me worry that Rails may be using the built/installed version of the code instead of the live source. What am I doing wrong?

---

* That is, it runs, even though it complains "Bundler is using a binstub that was created for a different gem". Possibly because it doesn't like the fact that the gem is named `my-engine` but the `ENGINE_PATH` has `my/engine`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like somehow the local gem setup on this machine was corrupted -- even if I created a brand-new unrelated engine, it still complained about not being able to find `my-engine`. `rm -r ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1*` / `gem install rails` fixed the problem (though at the price of having to reinstall a bunch of gems).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to call `rails -v` within the engine root since an engine is a gem after all that need to be loaded in a rails application, unless you have it structured like a normal rails app instead of an engine gem.

So basically, when you run `rails -v`, it will try to load your engine as a gem not as a normal rails application thus it will complain if its not installed in your environment.

Comment: That's not actually true. If you run rails -v after following the example from [Getting started with engines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), `rails plugin new blorgh --mountable; cd blorg; rails -v`, it works fine (at least with Ruby 2.2.1).